# Send request from Sencha touch app to Node.js server

Tags: node.js, request, sencha-touch

I started coding with Sencha Touch recently and I would like to make a simple app with a button that send a request to a Node.js server. Then I would like to display a simple message for seeing that the server received the request.

I tried Ext.Ajax.request and Ext.data.JsonP.request but without success... I searched a lot and tried a lot of things.

Right now my code app-side looks like :

```
    launch: function() {

    var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        iconCls: 'action',
        ui: 'action',
        handler: function() {
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'localhost:8080',
                success: function (response) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Success');
                },

                failure: function (response) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Failure');
                }
            });
        },
    });

    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
        fullscreen: true,
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            pack: 'center',
            align: 'center'
        },
        items: [
            {
                html: 'Send The Request'
            },
            {
                items: [button]
            }
        ]
    }));
},
```

and the server-side is :

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var page = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log(page);
    response.writeHead(200);
});

server.on('request', function(request, response) {
    response.end('42');
});

server.listen(8080);
```

I know these codes are crap, be indulgent I'm very newbie in javascript.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

localhost:8080 will not work deploying the app on a phone, as it will target the phone itself (but it's ok for testing from a browser). url should require the protocol too (http://).

Comment: I forgot to specify that I test it with Wamp (for app-side). The app at localhost/MyApp and the server at localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug this and work out at what point the request is failing.

You can try console.log'ing from node to see if the request is ever received. Or, open the app in Chrome and use the inspector's network tab to see if the request ever gets sent, and if so what (if any) the response is.

Comment: I already tried to debug. The line "console.log(page);" display the page requested when I connect on localhost:8080 on Google Chrome and I see the response '42' . But when I try to send the request with my app it doesn't work, nothing is displayed in the node.js console. So I think my current app code doesn't send any request.

Comment: If you read my comment in more detail, you'll see I suggested you use the inspector's network tab to see if the request ever gets sent. There's more to debugging than print statements.

Comment: Yes, I checked it and there is no request.

Comment: Does the event handler on the button fire? Have you tried with setting a method on the Ajax request? To get or post. Have you tried using the inspector's console to type in the javascript code to fire the request?